# Difference between array and pointer as a function's argument in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When defining a function like this:

```
void  myFunction(arguments){
   // some instructions
}
```

What is the deference between using `type name[]` and `type *name` as the function's argument.

When using `type name[]` and calling the function does it make a copy to the `name` array or just point to the passed array.

Is the `name` array's subscript needs to be set. If not what's the difference.

Comment: @Kerrek_SB It's not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either way only a pointer is passed.

```
void f(int array[]);
```

is synonymous to passing a const pointer

```
void f( int * const array);
```

---

They become non-synonymous when passing two dimensional arrays with bounds

```
void f(int array[][n]);
```

is synonymous to

```
void f(int (* const array)[n]);
```

But **different** to

```
void f(int **array);
```

Comment: `int array[][n]` is an array of pointers to int where `int **array` is a pointer to pointer to int.
Is that right?

Comment: @rullof `int array[][n]` is an array of/a pointer to an undefined amount of arrays of `n` `int`s (single block of memory). While `int ** array` is an array of pointers to `int` (each of which can point to it's own separate block of memory holding an undefined amount of `int`s).

Comment: For the first one you'r right just it's an undefined amount of int not array of int. the second one (int **array) i don't think so, it's just a pointer to pointer to int. `array` is just the name otherwise you means something else

Comment: An `int array[]` parameter is **not** adjusted to `int * const array`. It is just `int *array`; there is no `const`. If the parameter were `int array[const]`, then it would be adjusted to `int * const array`. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.6.3 7: “A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.”

Comment: This is wrong. Eric Postpischil is right. `array` is `int *`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference to my knowledge which is actually a problem in this situation:

```
int func(int a[20]) {
    sizeof(a); // equals sizeof(int*)!!
}
```

Therefore I always prefer the pointer form, as the array form can cause subtle confusion.

Answer (score -2):

In C++ it's the same. Different is in declaration;

```
char *s = "String"; // allocated and fill
char str[80];      // allocated memory
char *p1;          // not allocated memory
p1 = str;
```

Comment: The statements in this answer are about declarations within a block. The question is about function parameters, which behave differently.