# Why would one ever declare a parameter of type array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, coding-style

According to "[Difference between passing array and array pointer into function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5573310)", there's no semantic difference between these two ways of declaring parameters since "array parameters [are being] treated as though they were declared as pointers".

```
void f1(int a[]) { /* ... */ }
void f2(int* a)  { /* ... */ }
```

There is, however, a big difference between dealing with arrays and pointers. One could, for example, find out the size of an array using `sizeof(some_array)`. When dealing with a pointer, though, this is just going to reveal the size of the pointer itself. (Sidenote: [This](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/25/c-single-member-structs/) is a pretty neat workaround concerning that issue.)

This is why I find it to be misleading to declare parameters like that: `f1(int a[])`. As *djechlin* pointed out in "[Difference between array and pointer as a function's argument in c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20218903)", I think it can trick one into thinking that one is actually dealing with arrays instead of just pointers: **"Therefore I always prefer the pointer form, as the array form can cause subtle confusion."**

That being said, I wonder why people keep using the "array form" as there seems to be no reason to do so. What am I missing here? In his book [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/), [Zed Shaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zed_Shaw) actually mixes both ways:

```
void print_arguments(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
```

They also do it in K&R2.

Why? I am familiar with the reasons for not doing it, but what are the pros?

Comment: The array notation indicates *intent*: The pointer is meant to point into an array, rather than to a single element.

Comment: `char* argv[]` is immediately obvious as being an array of strings. `char** argv` is not quite so plainly written.

Comment: The reason is the same as for using code indentation and long identifiers. You know, they make no semantic difference.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with statement about `sizeof`, but `sizeof` only gives *declared*, compile time size of array. It does not really work with function parameters in useful manner.

Comment: @Matt: Butt only because you know `argv` is such per convention. Otherwise it would only be an array of `char*`.

Comment: @hyde I'll try to express this better. I am aware of the fact that `sizeof` is quite useless with parameters. Thanks for pointing it out, though!

Comment: While you're at it lets also continue the related and equally important argument about whether we write `char* foo` or `char *foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which one is easier to understand:

```
char *argv[] is intended to be an array of pointers to chars
```

or

```
char **argv is a pointer to a pointer to a char
```

Yes, you can code C in a non-intuitive way, but why would you?

Which do you prefer:

```
a[2]
*(a + 2)
*(2 + a)
2[a]
```

all have the same effect.  Why use `[]` when it is just syntactic sugar?  Because it is more readable.  In a similar vein: `(*ps).member` is not as readable as `ps->member`

Answer (score 3):

Technically, I'm unaware of any reason, but semantically the meaning is a lot clearer.

If I see a function take a pointer to something, I would expect it to be a single item unless the variable name (and/or possibly function name) makes it clear that it will be anticipating an array.

Whereas if it is labelled as taking an array, that is quite obvious. This is especially the case with multiple `**` - take the `char *argv[]` example. That is clearly a pointer to an array of `char*`'s (i.e. strings). `char **argv` could be that, but it could also be a mutable pointer (e.g. for freeing). While `char argv[][]` would imply a two dimensional array (something `char *argv[]` does not).

Answer (score 0):

Although both declaration are same , first one is preferable when you want to pass a pointer to an array. One can easily understand that.
In case of latter, it is not predictable that whether you are passing a pointer to a single element or an array.